# Edit UAC Protected file in windows

Tags: java, java-io

How to edit and save uac protected files especially the hosts file (DNS mapping) through bat file / java.

Java throws IO exception. Because the file is not writable. Set write also fails.

```
   File file = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
   file.setWritable(true);
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "127.0.0.1 test.com", true);
```

Exception 
      File 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' cannot be written to

Comment: You don't have write privileges to host file. First give write privileges and try

Comment: Is it possible to do that in Java. I tried setWritable(true) it is failing. I want to do it in Java/Windows shell.

Comment: You have to give permission form OS(Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give write permission default host file has read and execute permission only

[image]

Comment: Can you show me how to change via shell script or java. I’d like to change it to write for all users

Comment: According to my knowledge it cannot change from jave please Google for shell scripts l'm not well familiar with shell scripts